# return string in com.sun.jna.Memory causes JVM crash

Tags: java, jna, autoit

I am trying to call AutoItX (a closed-source .dll library) from Java using JNA.
I used [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access), [this blog](http://blog.mwrobel.eu/how-to-call-dll-methods-from-java/), plus various posts on here to help me through this difficult time.

I started with the .h file and translated that to a Java `interface`, and started building out all the easy methods - ones that take only `int` or `WString` as arguments. Being the paranoid type, I was also building up unit tests to prove that everything is working. All my source can be found on [sourceforge](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/sebase/code/sebase-groovy/src/test/java/net/sourceforge/sebase/autoit).

The problems start when I work with some of the methods that return stuff in one of the passed arguments.

From the header file, I took:

```
AU3_API void WINAPI AU3_WinGetText(LPCWSTR szTitle, LPCWSTR szText, LPWSTR szRetText, int nBufSize);
```

The `szRetText` is where I am going to get my value back. In Java I translated this to:

```
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.WString;
void AU3_WinGetText(WString szTitle, WString szText, Memory szRetText, int nBufSize);
```

and I try to call this with:

```
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.WString;
public String winGetText(String szTitle) {
    Memory szRetText = new Memory(256);
    autoItX.AU3_WinGetText(new WString(szTitle), new WString(""), szRetText, 255);
    return szRetText.getString(0, true);
}
```

When I try to run this in my unit test by itself, it works fine. When I run the entire suite, the test immediately following this one always crashes the JVM.
I tried a few different methods with similar signature, with the same results.

Any advice where to next?

Please note that I am aware of [jwinauto](http://jwinauto.sourceforge.net/) (and there may be others); however, I am doing this as a learning exercise.

Comment: You're telling it the buffer has room for 255 characters, when it doesn't -- `wchar_t` requires at least two bytes on windows.  If you pass `char[]` instead, and pass the length of the array as `nBufSize`, you should get better results.  Then use `Native.toString(char[])` to convert back to a Java `String`.  Alternatively, double the size of your allocated `Memory`.

Comment: Totally works, thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @technomage advice, I ended up using:

```
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.WString;
public String winGetText(String szTitle) {
   Memory szRetText = new Memory(2 * 256);
   autoItX.AU3_WinGetText(new WString(szTitle), new WString(""), szRetText, 256);
   return szRetText.getString(0, true);
}
```

The only change is to allocate double the `Memory()`, everything else is the same.
I felt this approach was more JNA-friendly than using `char[]`.